# getQauntdate() method explanation

Tags: java, go

can someone explain to me the function of this methode that i found in a script:

```
public static String getQuantDate(final int quant) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
        final int dayOfYear = quant;
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
        final Date dat = calendar.getTime();
        return sdf.format(dat);
    }
```

i need to traslate it to golang but i didn't understand the functionalities to translate it!

Comment: It converts a day number in the current year to a string with month and day number; for example, today is day 213 of the year 2017, when you pass 213 to this method it returns a string `"0801"` (August 1).

Comment: @Jesper yeah, it seems pretty broken though. Doesn't accept the year as input, so there is really no way to handle leap years appropriately.

Comment: @captncraig indeed, it always uses the current year, so if you call this method in a leap year after Feb 29 it will give a different result than in a non-leap year for the same input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotated:

```
   // format string. This returns MMdd
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");

    //redundant re-declaration of function parameter
    final int dayOfYear = quant;

    // make a date and set DAY_OF_YEAR to quant
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);

    // get date and return it in the correct format
    final Date dat = calendar.getTime();
    return sdf.format(dat);
```

Looks like the funtion takes a number, converts it to a date, and formats it.

`1` would yield `0101`

`13` would give `0113`

`32` would give `0201`

and so forth.

It is not clear though, how this handles leap years and other variables like that. It does not seem like very high quality code, and I'd recommend analyzing your problem, and coming up with a good spec.